# Enum Property Error: expected a string enum, not tuple

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm writing an addon that generates a list of categories that I want to set in an enum property. The enum property is defined as such:

```
class PipelineProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    asset_categories = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Asset Categories",
        description="Categories for Project Specific Assets",
        items=[
            ('init', 'init', 'test', 0)
        ]
    )


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.pipe = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Pipeline Properties', type=PipelineProperties)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.pipe
```

The enum property is accessed by:

```
bpy.context.scene.pipe.asset_categories
```

Here is the code where I assign a new value to this enum property:

```
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.pipe.asset_categories = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name='Asset Categories',
            description='Testing',
            items=[('new', 'new', 'test value', 0)]
        )
```

Here is the error message:

```
scn.pipe.asset_categories = bpy.props.EnumProperty(as_name_list)
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: expected a string enum, not tuple
```

What is this error and why am I getting it? How would I go about setting the value of the enum property I have defined to something else?

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to assign a property definition as a property value:

```
scn.pipe.asset_categories = bpy.props.EnumProperty(...)
```

Should be:

```
scn.pipe.asset_categories = 'new'
```

Or, if you actually want to change the definition, uou must manipulate the type instead of it's instance:

```
del bpy.types.Scene.pipe
bpy.types.Scene.pipe = bpy.props.EnumProperty(...)
```

*Where `...` are all the enum arguments*

Comment: What if I have a long list of these different categories? Say for example 'new, blue, true', and I want the enum property to hold all of these new values?

Comment: @lvxejay please ask a separate question for that (its not closely related to this one)